# How to sort only few elements in an array of object by date property

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects like below.

```
var array = [{id: 1, date:'Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 2, date:'Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 3, date:'Mar 15 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 4, date:'Mar 5 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 5, date:'Mar 30 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 6, date:'Mar 5 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 7, date:'Mar 1 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 8, date:'Mar 7 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'},
                 {id: 9, date:'Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'}, 
                 {id: 10, date:'Mar 2 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'}, 
                 {id: 11, date:'Mar 6 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notexist'}, 
                 {id: 12, date:'Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'notexist'}];
```

I am trying to sort first few elements in my array which has `status:'done'` and leave remaining records as it is.

Can someone help me with how I can put this condition and `sort` the elements.

Thanks.

Comment: What nobody is telling you in the answers below, is that the approach they're taking to create a `Date` object from a string, is fraught with risks. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [{id: 1, date:'Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 2, date:'Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 3, date:'Mar 15 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 4, date:'Mar 5 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 5, date:'Mar 30 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 6, date:'Mar 5 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 7, date:'Mar 1 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 8, date:'Mar 7 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'},
                 {id: 9, date:'Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'}, 
                 {id: 10, date:'Mar 2 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'}, 
                 {id: 11, date:'Mar 6 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notexist'}, 
                 {id: 12, date:'Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'notexist'}];
                 
var doneItems = array.filter(r => r.status === 'done');
var remainingItems = array.filter(r => r.status !== 'done');

doneItems.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)));

console.log(doneItems.concat(remainingItems));
```

Comment: @brig Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sorted = array.reduce((prev, curr, i, xs) => {
  // push into either the first or second sub-array based on status
  const idx = curr.status === 'done' ? 0 : 1
  prev[idx].push(curr)

  // if on the last element, sort the first array
  // the check is just to avoid running the sort on every iteration
  if (i === xs.length - 1) {
    prev[0].sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
  }

  return prev

// initialize with a 2d array, flatten when it's all done
}, [[],[]]).flat()
```

Answer (score 1):

All in one solution:

```js
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.status === 'done' && b.status === 'done') {
        return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    } else if (a.status === 'done') {
        return -1;
    } else if (b.status === 'done') {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter by status, then sort by Date:

```js
var array = [{id: 1, date:'Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 2, date:'Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 3, date:'Mar 15 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 4, date:'Mar 5 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 5, date:'Mar 30 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 6, date:'Mar 5 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'done'},
                 {id: 7, date:'Mar 1 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'done'}, 
                 {id: 8, date:'Mar 7 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'},
                 {id: 9, date:'Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'}, 
                 {id: 10, date:'Mar 2 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notdone'}, 
                 {id: 11, date:'Mar 6 2012 10:00:00 AM', status:'notexist'}, 
                 {id: 12, date:'Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM', status:'notexist'}];
 
let filtered = array.filter(x => x.status == 'done') ;
let sorted = filtered.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
console.log(sorted)

// concat the 'non done' status items:
let rest = array.filter(x => x.status != 'done');
console.log(sorted.concat(rest))
```